# Mongodb return an Empty array

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I am trying to make a range query and show the data in my ejs view

EJS View "historicos.ejs"

```
<h1>historicos</h1>
<form action="/historicos/buscar">
    <input type="text" name='inicio' id='inicio'></li>
    <input type="text" name='final' id='final'></li>


    <br>
    <button type="submit">Buscar</button>
</form>


<% if(typeof his !== 'undefined'){ 

    his.forEach(function(dati){%>

    <%= dati.temp %>
    <%= dati.hum %>
    <%= dati.date %>
    <br/>

    <%});
    }; %>
```

I am using a controller with 2 methods, 1 for render the page and one to manage the query.

Controller "grafi.js"

```
var Si = require('../models/sis');

exports.getPagehis = function(req, res) {
    if (req.user) return res.redirect('/');
        res.render('historicos');
    };

exports.getHis= function(req, res, next) {

    ini = req.body.inicio;
    fin = req.body.final;
    console.log(ini)
    console.log(fin)


    Si.find({"date": {"$gte":ini, "$lt":fin}},function(err, his) {
        console.log(his);
    if(err) return next(err);
    res.render('historicos', {
        his:his
    });
    });

};
```

and this is my router file

```
router.get('/historicos', hiController.getPagehis);
router.get('/historicos/buscar', hiController.getHis);
```

if I write manually ini and fin to make the query(using this format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm), I mean without the req.body.inicial and req.body.final, it work well but when I request the information from the view I got this fields undifined.

what can i do to solve this?

Comment: You have validated on the server that `req.body.inicio` and `req.body.final` are in the same format as `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm` and not encoded or escaped?

Comment: yeah,as i said if i write the string in that format it work good

Comment: That validates that a string in that format works but not that the param values are of that form. Have you either debugged or console.log the passed in values?

Comment: Yes my friend, I used console.log(variables) to check what is passed to that variables and it said undifined

Comment: So the server code might be okay. Have you inspected the request from the browser to see if it includes the params?

Comment: how can I check that ?

Comment: You can either inspect the request that is sent from the browser using the [developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) or by inspecting the request on the server (with a [debugger](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) or simply doing something like: `console.log(req.body)`). I would recommend starting with the browser dev tools and if that looks correct then checking the request received by the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was form and the request in general adding method="get" in the form and update the controller with:

```
var Url = require('url');

...

queryparams = Url.parse(req.url,true).query;
    ini = queryparams.ini;
    fi = queryparams.fi;
... make the query to mongo db
```

with this code is possible to get the values in the input files passed in the url